# Is there a Semitic zonal language?

Tags: zonal-languages

I am familiar with zonal languages that attempt to smooth out and simplify the differences between languages within a family, such as Slovio for the Slavic languages and Folkspraak for the Germanic languages. Is there an existing zonal language or language project for the [Semitic language family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_languages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not easy to find!

A bit of jazz Semitic auxlanging [going on here](https://conlangs.livejournal.com/126240.html).

[Ayvarith](http://www.travelphrases.info/languages/conlangs.htm) seems to be an invented language based on Hebrew, Arabic and Aramaic.